# How to write eof in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out How to write `if eof` in python for dbf files ? I know python doesn't use eof but I'm trying to read records from a dbf file.

Comment: `read` or `readline` return an empty string on EOF. Is that what you need?

Comment: Do read and readline work for dbf files?